# Is there a left-handed equivalent of \implies?

Tags: amsmath, arrows

I use the `\implies` and `\iff` command for right-handed implication and if and only if (so A=>B and A<=>B).

What’s a similar command for left-handed implication (i.e., A<=B)? I couldn’t find anything in Google or the documentation.

Comment: There's also `\Leftarrow`

Comment: Take a look here : http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html . This gives `\Leftarrow`.

Comment: Also, you could try `\xleftarrow` from `mathtools` and use phantom text to elongate it to  make it look like the `\implies`.

Comment: Everyone always overlooks the obvious solution to a "missing" character macro: `\newcommand\follows{\Longleftarrow}`.

Comment: With `\usepackage{amsmath}` you have `\impliedby`

Comment: seems like a duplicate of the old favourite [how-to-look-up-a-symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Comment: @cmhughes Not really. The commands `\implies` and `\iff` are provided by `amsmath`, but somehow slipped away from the documentation. The command `\impliedby` is there also. The three behave correctly with respect to dots, while the `\Long...arrow` commands don't. The `symbol.pdf` file doesn't list them.

Comment: @egreg ok :) why not turn your comments into one of your trademark-excellent answers :)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The command you need is already there: `\impliedby` (if you're using `\implies` it means that you're loading `amsmath`).

The story is quite intricated. Let's try doing a resumé.

Plain TeX defines `\iff` as `\;\Longleftrightarrow\;`, that is, a relation symbol with extended spaces on its left and right.

In AMS-TeX the command was redefined so that it was "dots-aware":

```
\def\iff{\DOTSB\;\Longleftrightarrow\;}
```

and it was supplemented by similar commands

```
\def\implies{\DOTSB\;\Longrightarrow\;}
\def\impliedby{\DOTSB\;\Longleftarrow\;}
```

The three commands were transplanted in `amstex.sty` (the first porting of AMS-TeX to LaTeX) and found their way also in the "definitive" package `amsmath.sty`, but not in its documentation.

Since they are undocumented, they aren't really listed in the Comprehensive List of LaTeX Symbols (there are "see `\Longrightarrow`" and similar references).

A problem can arise from the fact the commands are not documented: they may disappear in new releases of `amsmath`. A solution for your documents is to say

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\providecommand\iff{\DOTSB\;\Longleftrightarrow\;}
\providecommand\implies{\DOTSB\;\Longrightarrow\;}
\providecommand\impliedby{\DOTSB\;\Longleftarrow\;}
```

but also this can be risky, since it uses the internal macro `\DOTSB`.

Since they *are* useful (although I usually stay away from them, preferring words) it would be a welcome addition that they find their way in the documentation of `amsmath`.

Comment: What does it mean for a symbol to be "dots-aware"?

Comment: @AndrewUzzell When you say `$a+\dots+z$` you get centered dots, when you say `$a,\dots,z$` the dots are low. Similarly, you automatically get centered dots with `$a\iff\dots\iff z$` because of `\DOTSB`

Comment: I see.  That's a neat feature.

Comment: Is there a more complete list of such undocumented symbol commands?  It seems that \to might belong here as well.

Comment: @AriBrodsky `\to` has been equivalent to `\rightarrow` since the beginning of (TeX) time. I've always taken for granted it's in the LaTeX manual, but to my surprise it isn't there.