# Purpose of DOTSB in definition of \iff

Tags: amsmath, mathtools, ellipsis

What exactly is the purpose of the `\DTOSB` in the definition of `\iff`? There is a mention in  [Is there a left-handed equivalent of \implies?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79839/is-there-a-left-handed-equivalent-of-implies) that the `\DOTSB` makes `\iff` "dots aware". But, when I try to use `\dots` on either side I don't see any difference.

Egreg commented that you need `\newcommand*` in order for `DOTSB` to have an effect. But, it seems that the definition with using the star option in `\newcommand*` differs from the definition of `\iff`. Its the

```
\newcommand{\MyIffWithDotsbNonStar}{\DOTSB\;\Longleftrightarrow \;}
```

the produces the same meaning as `\iff`.

[image]

### References:

- [How do magic \dots work in amsmath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649/how-do-magic-dots-work-in-amsmath)
- [Is there a left-handed equivalent of \implies?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79839/is-there-a-left-handed-equivalent-of-implies)
- [How can I make amsmath's \dots look ahead after macro expansion?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266718/how-can-i-make-amsmaths-dots-look-ahead-after-macro-expansion)

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10in]{geometry}% for better display of output

\newcommand{\MyIffWithDotsbNonStar}{\DOTSB\;\Longleftrightarrow \;}
\newcommand{\MyIffWithoutDotsbNonStar}{\;\Longleftrightarrow \;}

\newcommand*{\MyIffWithDotsbStar}{\DOTSB\;\Longleftrightarrow \;}
\newcommand*{\MyIffWithoutDotsbStar}{\;\Longleftrightarrow \;}

\begin{document}
\par \verb|\iff|: \texttt{\meaning\iff}
\par \verb|\MyIffWithDotsbNonStar|: \texttt{\meaning\MyIffWithDotsbNonStar}
\par \verb|\MyIffWithDotsbStar|: \texttt{\meaning\MyIffWithDotsbStar}

\medskip
\par $a \iff b$ using \verb|\iff|
\par $a \MyIffWithDotsbNonStar b$ using \verb|\MyIffWithDotsbNonStar|
\par $a \MyIffWithoutDotsbNonStar b$ using \verb|\MyIffWithoutDotsbNonStar|
\par $a \MyIffWithDotsbStar b$ using \verb|\MyIffWithDotsbStar|
\par $a \MyIffWithoutDotsbStar b$ using \verb|\MyIffWithoutDotsbStar|


\medskip
\par $a \dots \iff \dots b$ using \verb|\dots \iff \dots|
\par $a \dots \MyIffWithDotsbNonStar \dots b$ using \verb|\dots \MyIffWithDotsbNonStar \dots|
\par $a \dots \MyIffWithoutDotsbNonStar \dots b$ using \verb|\dots \MyIffWithoutDotsbNonStar \dots|
\par $a \dots \MyIffWithDotsbStar \dots b$ using \verb|\dots \MyIffWithDotsbStar \dots| \textcolor{red}{\bfseries DIFFERS}
\par $a \dots \MyIffWithoutDotsbStar \dots b$ using \verb|\dots \MyIffWithoutDotsbStar \dots|

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\newcommand*` in order `\DOTSB` to have an effect, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266721/4427

Comment: @egreg: It seems that `\meaning\iff` and `\meaning\MyIffWithDotsbNonStar` (defined with `\newcommand` (i.e. without the star option) gives the same meaning.

Comment: Yes, `\iff` has a wrong definition in `amsmath.sty`

Comment: I'd like to know as well. Was editing a set of notes and was using a variant of iff where I'd added a quad on both sides. You can see the alignment difference if you add it into an align

Comment: @egreg: And that isn't fixed by the  `mathtools` package?  Is there some package that should be included that has these kinds of fixes?

Comment: @PeterGrill No, `mathtools` doesn't change the meaning of `\iff` as defined by `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg: So then the correct redefinition would be `\renewcommand*{\iff}{\DOTSB\;\Longleftrightarrow\;}`?

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, of course.

Comment: @egreg -- in defense of `amsmath`, i don't believe that `\newcommand*` existed when it was created; certainly `\newcommand*` is not even mentioned in lamport, nor is there any indication (p.192) that anything defined with `\newcommand` is automatically `\long`.  i'm adding this problem to the `amsmath` bugs list, but please let me know what other commands are similarly erroneously `\long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `amsmath` 2.15 then you can use `\newcommand` or `\newcommand*` as `\long` is ignored when checking the `\meaning`. This means that `\dots` now works as intended with `\iff` and gives centred dots.

[image]

Comment: Does this ignore `\protected` too?

Comment: @Manuel No, one thing at a time:-)  main reason for changing it was to make it work in luatex which in development builds never reports \mathchar in \meaning any more, and fixing \long so the package's own definition of iff and related arrows worked as intended seemed hard to avoid:-)

Comment: Okey, I thought it would be easier to gobble everything until `->` and look for `\DOTSB`.

Comment: @Manuel I really wanted to minimize changes in pdftex this time round (I even considered not fixing the \long bug)  agreement with AMS was that we'd update it to make it work in luatex and not mess up the pdftex workflow...